# Xamarin Forms always connected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've been tasked with writing an application for Android that communicates to an API our our office.  The API will be pushing data to the phone and the phone responds back.  The phone app must be able to take the push anytime after the app is activated like email or text.

Sorry I don't have any code written yet.
I thought I'd write this in Xamarin Forms, in case they want to port this to IOS.   I've written a comm app in Xamarin before but when another app was in focus, it stopped communicating.

The app must not go to sleep when another app is brought into focus as most of them seem to do.
It has to work like a Text app or Email app, and I have no idea what I'm looking for.
Google gives me ways to text and email, but I haven't found anything that helps in a keep alive state until the user shuts it down.
Any links or key words would be super helpful.

Comment: Look at Foreground Services : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/ And/Or use Push notifications to keep the app in sync with new updates from your server

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out.